# Is it possible to use SceneKit elements with a GLKit project?

Tags: xcode, opengl, 3d, scenekit, glkit

So a creative person on my team wants us to use SceneKit's built in material functionality to render 3D objects within our project, which is currently built in GLKit. I'm trying to figure out a way to do it. Is it even possible? Are there any specific conflicts I should be looking out for? I'm a little lost on this one so if you have any links to sample projects that use the two together that would be *amazing*. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I talked to someone at Apple and apparently you can use glkit elements with scenekit but not the other way around due to scenekit dependencies. Looks like someone's going to have to do a refactor. Womp womp.